# how to Map a window to 3D

Tags: windows, 3d, direct3d

I'm searching for how to render window to 3D windows Texture on D3D
for example, the windows aero-glass's preview.
a window or part of window that has a windows handler is rendered to a d3d device(i guess aero glass is maked by d3d). 
my project is a 3D interective media. it is an AR project using HMD and Hand Recognizing.(Like a 3d touch interaction )My part is 3D Rendering. The WPF can do this. But i don't find the way how to do it with D3D. 
Who knows the way or it is impossible on D3D? if you know, please notice me a KEYWORD that using to Google. 
thanks to reading and your attention. i'm not native english user and i'm sorry that if you feel my english seems ugly.

Comment: DWM.exe seems to use some internal libraries to do this. I don't think it's possible to do this with 3rd party applications.

Comment: i know the simple solution. here's that:<br />
copy target window's hdc buffer to IDirect3DTexture9. for this way it cant be avoid texture lock and copying each frame. but i think it is only and simple solution

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest using dynamic textures. You first create a texture of the desired size and format. Then you get its surface, obtain HDC and pass it to a window you want be drawn. Showing a texture thru d3d device shouldn't be a problem.